# Apply a class name in table

Tags: css

I know how to do this:

```
td {  
    border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;  
      border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;  
}
```

But i already have a separate css class called 'tdclass'. I have referenced it using `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"`. How do I apply this tdclass to td?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot apply a class through a CSS document. You need to add `class="tdclass"` in the HTML portion.

Answer (score 2):

in your html you change the `<td>` to `<td class="tdclass">`

Comment: please i do not want to mix html with css. How do I do using what I asked?

Comment: you have to referrer in some way in your html document what class you want to use. If you can't change the html, then you can change your css like `.tdclass, td {properties}` this will apply the properties to any element with class `tdclass` and any `td` of the document.

Comment: @learningdb can I ask you,what part of the above code is CSS? "class" is a HTML attribute and "tdclass" is the value of "class" attribute which refer to CSS class.

Answer (score 2):

Between the head tags of your htmlpage

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="PATH_TO_YOUR_STYLESHEET.css" type="text/css">
```

In this css file you put

```
.tdclass{

WATHEVER CSS YOU NEED

}
```

to limit it to td tags with this class you could change it to:

```
td.tdclass{

WATHEVER CSS YOU NEED

}
```

Next in your HTML file add your class to each `<td>` you want to apply it to like this:

```
<td class="tdclass">
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS:

```
td { /*things to apply go in here */ }
```

or, in your HTML:

```
<td class="tdclass">
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a class in HTML:

```
<td class="yourClassNameGoesHere"></td>
```

You can then reference that class in your CSS file with:

```
.yourClassNameGoesHere {
      border-right:1px solid #C1DAD7;
      ...
}
```

To reference *just* table cells with that class, use

```
td.yourClassNameGoesHere {
      ...
}
```